# How to include a file with the verbatim environment

Tags: verbatim, input

I would like to include a file within the `verbatim` environment but this of course doesn't work:

```
\begin{verbatim}
    \input{file.tex}
\end{verbatim}
```

Is there way of getting LaTeX to execute `\input` within the verbatim environment?

Please trust me that I have good reasons for wanting to do this.

Comment: Maybe the `listings` package could be useful, it has the command `\lstinputlisting` to input source files

Comment: Welcome to the site.  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\verbatiminput{MYFILE.tex}
\end{document}`.  See also the `verbatimbox` package: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\verbfilenobox[\small]{MYFILE.tex}

\verbfilebox[\tiny]{MYFILE.tex}\fbox{\theverbbox}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this file is named junk.tex, here is a plug for my `verbatimbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
Normal sized text
\verbfilenobox[\theVerbboxLineNo: \Large]{junk.tex}
\verbfilebox[\tiny]{junk.tex}\fbox{\theverbbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `verbatim` package, it is this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\begin{document} 
\verbatiminput{junk.tex} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

As samcarter noted, there are other even more flexible options, such as the `listings` package.